# UITypeEditor working principles

Tags: c#, .net, propertygrid, uitypeeditor, icustomtypedescriptor

I would like to get a thorough understanding of how does UITypeEditor uses the PropertyGrid to add more functionality to it. I've found some working examples but this does not help much in trying to understand how does it work. I want to use UITypeEditor for the custom-made 3rd party PropertyGrid implementing ICustomTypeDescriptor but it doesn't work.

Any tips or explanations are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work?"

Comment: It does not show an icon on the bottom right corner of the text input. I cannot access EditValue method.

Comment: `PropertyGrid` uses the `UITypeEditor` to modify itself, `UITypeEditor` does not know anything about the property grid. Without seeing how you implement your `UITypeEditor`, a description of what you are trying to accomplish, or the property grid library you are using, its going to be **extremely** difficult to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip that makes it a bit more clear. The PropertyGrid is custom made and has too much code to post it here. Having some information about how does PropertyGrid.SelectedObject attaches UITypeEditor would definitely help.

Comment: It appears to function properly when I add it to the same assembly. There are all necessary references to the assemblies and compilation gives no error. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Some people suggest using [Editor("namespace.classname", typeof(UITypeEditor))] but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: *"Having some information about how does PropertyGrid.SelectedObject attaches UITypeEditor"* Considering its a custom library, and we don't know anything about it, thats an impossible question to answer. Since you have the code for it though, it should be easy to look through and figure it out. I could point you to the standard .NET implementation, but it probably won't apply to a custom property grid.

Comment: does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609292/custom-editors-in-a-property-grid-that-uses-dictionary give you the working example you desire?

Comment: It works under one condition: the "custom UITypeEditor", which inherits from standard .NET "UITypeEditor" has to be in the same assembly as the property, which uses the Editor attribute. If it is placed into another assembly then it fails. But there must be a way to make it work between different assemblies.